# Question on trigonometric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Total number of solutions of $|\cos x| = \cot x +{1\over\sin x}$ in $[0, 3π]$, is equal to

(1) $1$
(2) $2$
(3) $3$
(4) $0$

I tried this question a lot by considering cosx<0 and cosx>0 but couldn't solve it.Hence this post.

Comment: Take a look here for latex: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Since it's a mod function,I think it quite likely has two solutions.but can anyone tell me how should I go about with it.

Comment: @YashLekhwani Check range of RHS

Comment: Hi everyone, I am a 12th grader.please don't down vote or put my question on hold unnecessarily.It is really discouraging to put up my doubts as I have no other source of help.If you don't feel like answering you may not.Any thoughts that I have given to my question and I feel is worth sharing I will definitely do so.Besides,Im new to latex so would have bit of a problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider the function $$f(x)=|\cos x| -( \cot x +{1\over\sin x})$$ and, for the time being, just consider the range $0<x<2 \pi$. You can easily show that $f(0)=-\infty$ and that $f(2\pi)=\infty$; so, there is at least one solution of $f(x)=0$ in this range. Futhermore, and taking care about limits, $f(\pi)=1$ so the solution is smallest that $\pi$. Since the function is periodic, the next root will be between $2 \pi$ and $3 \pi$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand but the hint is not really clear to me.pls elaborate.thanks.